# На каких языках пишутся информационные системы?

Tags: c#, 1с

Знаю, что можно написать, используя 1C:Предприятие, ещё знаком с C# в Visual Studio, где сразу визуально можно окно сделать. Интересует именно как приложение, а не через web используя браузер.

Comment: На чем угодно. C#, C++, Python, Go, Rust, Java. В вебе тоже приложения, если что, и это можно всё применять так же для десктопных приложений (Electron, Cordova и т.п). 1C, кстати, так себе пример для написания нормальных программ — это больше костыли для бухгалтеров.

Comment: А кроме C# c Visual Studio есть ещё что-нибудь с визуальным редактированием окон?

Comment: Лично я для таких целей использую Python с GUI Tkinter ну и сервер с БД, однако Python может оказаться не самым лучшим выбором для клиентской части, тот же C# или Java за счет статической типизации и JIT компиляции имеет очевидное преимущество.

Comment: Зачем это всё, когда есть XAML?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, "... это костыли для бухгалтеров" - можете обосновать?

Comment: @Sagittarius А Вы видели много адекватных программ общего назначения на 1C?))

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, предполагаю, что Ваша зарплата рассчитывается в 1С:ЗУП. Думаю, если пальцем ткнете в любую компанию, 90% что там есть одна из конфигураций для учета чего-либо. Это просто удобный инструмент для создания бизнес-приложений. Это не язык программирования, как многие говорят и начинают за это с пеной у рта доказывать, что 1С - *авно. То что с помощью других инструментов (языков, технологий и т.п.) надо будет делать очень долго, там решается на раз-два. Есть множество примеров внедрений в крупных корпорациях.

Comment: @Sagittarius моя зарплата сейчас точно в 1C не рассчитывается (подозреваю, что в SAP), да и до этого рассчитывалась во ФЛАГМАН. Да, 1С порешала рыночек в РФии, и Вы будете правы, что оно вездесуще, но это не значит, что оно лучшее, просто альтернативы тоже не особо хороши, или недоступны, или о них просто не знают, когда начинают работать. Именно потому что 1С не ЯП (условно) - поэтому и костыль.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, не говорил что оно "лучшее". Вот в этом и суть, что оно везде - куда пальцем не ткни. Альтернатив - не вижу (чтобы удобство/качество/цена). 
Да почему костыль?))) 
Есть молоток - он чтобы гвозди забивать, есть топор - дрова рубить. У каждого своё предназначение. Его не придумывали что бы на нем игры писать или создавать другое приложение. Меня передергивает когда его начинают с ЯП сравнивать.

Comment: @Sagittarius А почему его не сравнивать, если это и есть ЯП внутри софта (что в целом не особо отличается от нормальных языков, за исключением уж сильно обширных)? Так же может быть скомпилирован в исполняемое приложение, так же имеет свои конструкции и синтаксис. Понятное дело, что изначально не придумывали, но и какой-нибудь JS никто сначала не собирался использовать для игр и автоматизации механики... Костыль именно из-за кривости всего языка в целом. Альтернатива, чтобы сразу хорошо и как надо - самопис, чего и спрашивает автор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@user394501 Delphi с RAD Studio (он же Borland Developer Studio) - в своё время была топовой вещью, если не ошибаюсь именно с неё пошло формошлёпство в массы.

Крайне советую скачать Delphi 7 Lite (очень урезанная версия до 70-80мб, есть на rutracker) и потыкать её.
Сейчас уже сильно устарела и в основном существует за счёт легаси-кода (имхо).
Перешла в режим "умирания" ещё до 2010 года из-за большой задержки в развитии (COBOL тоже умирает но всё никак за 60+ лет помереть не может), в сравнении с набирающими тогда популярность C#, Java, C++/Qt и фреймворками для них, а так-же с бурным развитием Web'а, первую половину начала 2000х большинство формошлёпов сидели в Delphi (в том числе и под плюсами) и горя не знали.

Теперь же весь этот зоопарк различных информационных (не только бухгалтерских, есть программы для управляющих компаний, соцслужб, логистики, и им подобных, и не только) систем надо поддерживать, вот и сидит где-нибудь в тюмени отдел полубородатых дядек TПрограммистов за 50 и за пару копеек всё это дело обновляет. А всё почему - они в вёб не захотели =(
Новые приложения тоже пилятся на дельфях, но только по следующим причинам: основной язык группы программистов, формочки, есть готовая платформа/библиотеки/куски кода от предыдущей задачи.
А вовсе не потому, что: Delphi требует намного меньше памяти в сравнении с Java или C#, есть проверка выхода за пределы массива (можно включить/отключить) по скорости сопоставим с C++ (под Win, не кидайте тапками, там простые тесты), и имеет превосходную обратную совместимость - писал под винду до XP - запускай на Win10, и это без всяких JRE/.NET/C++Redist, итд...

PS Мобильные приложения в новой среде RAD Studio то-же как-то клепают.

Answer (score 1):

Местные программисты пишут нам ИС на Qt5.  Там есть визуальный редактор.

Визуальный редактор также есть для  Gtk. Но в gtk почти нет ничего для старта кроме окошек.

1с и SAP отличные системы и для написания учёта с нуля. Подкупает визуальное проектирование базы данных.

Ещё до сих пор некоторые пишут учёт на Foxpro.

Comment: Визуальное пронктирование бд есть и в Visual Studio

Comment: Визуальное проектирование БД есть в программах для визуального проектирования БД, как бы это абсурдно не звучало)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar пректирование схемы и проектирование бизнес логики это разнве вещи